# Running updatedb as a nomal user (using the plocate package)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, sudo, locate

I want a normal user to be able to update the database used by the `locate` command in Linux.  With the previous version of `locate` (provided by the package `mlocate`), I achieved this by adding the following entry into `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/updatedb
```

However, this doesn't work with the new version of `locate` (provided by the package `plocate`), which prints the following error when running `updatedb`:

```
/var/lib/plocate/: Permission denied
```

What is the simplest way to allow a normal user to run `updatedb`?

PS: there's a similar question to mine from [2012](https://superuser.com/questions/467181/how-to-use-updatedb-command-as-an-ordinary-user), but it is for an older package, `slocate`.

Comment: One way to do updatedb w/o `sudo` is using `doas`. see [man doas](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/doas/doas.1.en.html) and [man doas.conf](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/doas/doas.conf.5.en.html).

Comment: Thank you!  This worked well.  Will update the question with the answer.

Comment: Please note, these aren't discussion forums. If you have an answer, you should [write an answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and later [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it, or accept someone else's, not edit your question. That way this question gets closed and marked as resolved so it'll be helpful for others facing the same issue. Also if there is no accepted answer, the question will pop up again and again as [Unanswered](https://superuser.com/unanswered) for years to come...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to use `updatedb` w/o `sudo` is using `doas`.

`doas` is configured with `/etc/doas.conf`. The configuration has a simple structure:

`permit nopass <user> as <another user> cmd <command>`

For example, my `doas.conf`:

```
permit nopass pg as root cmd apt 
permit nopass pg as root cmd dmesg
permit nopass pg as root cmd mount
permit nopass pg as root cmd umount
permit nopass pg as root cmd updatedb
```

With this I'm able to run commands `apt`, `dmesg`, `mount`, `umount` and `updatedb` without `sudo`. The format of the command on CLI is

```
doas updatedb
```

For further info:

- `doas` [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/doas/doas.1.en.html)
- `doas.conf` [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/doas/doas.conf.5.en.html)